# Why does Windows' "Pause" option when moving/copying files take so long to work?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, windows-explorer, file-transfer, thunderbolt

I have just bought a Samsung T7 1 TB SSD and am trying to move ~200 GB of data on to it from my laptop's internal SSD. I stupidly tried to do this with File Explorer's built-in move capabilities instead of copying, verifying and *then* deleting the source data. After realising my mistake, and that the process was taking far, far longer than it should (using a Thunderbolt 3 port and an SSD that has crazy-good reviews), I tried to pause the process, which gives me this:

[image: File Explorer copy window]

It has said "Pausing" since about 15% of the way through the entire process, and as you can see, it's now progressed another 9% (which amounts to hundreds of small files and many MBs of data) **without actually pausing!** This raises two major questions, and a third, less-important one in my mind:

1. Why didn't Windows pause the operation like I asked it to *immediately*?? I understand that it may have first needed to finish the I/O operation that it was currently processing, but surely that would mean *the single file* that it was working on at *the precise moment* of clicking the pause button, would it not?
2. How on Earth does Windows actually achieve this functionality? What are the Win32 API functions involved in both the copying and pausing processes, as accessed through File Explorer and this dialog?
3. Why are third-party programs like TeraCopy so much better at handling Windows file I/O than *the OS itself*?! This seems utterly ludicrous to me!

Comment: Honestly, the copying probably failed.  However, there isn’t any difference, between the two actions since they use the same underlining mechanism

Comment: *there isn’t any difference between the two actions since they use the same underlining mechanism* - If you mean no difference between copying and moving, that's what I expected...a move is just a copy, immediately followed by a delete right? But if you're talking about something else, please clarify. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Similar question>>>https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/6e28f695-e49d-466e-86d3-62881dc2a6e8/file-copy-is-stuck-with-quotpausing-65-completequot-after-clicking-the-pause-button?forum=winserver8gen

Comment: @Moab Yeah I came across that page when Googling the issue, but it didn't answer my larger, more specific questions. Hence why I asked you fine folks :-)